# How does one integrate Game Center leaderboards in Monogame?

Tags: c#, monogame, leaderboards, game-center

Do anyone know how to integrate a Game Center leaderboards for an iOS game using MonoGame framework?

I have searched high and low yet I haven't gotten any luck of finding articles or tutorials that talks about the topic of Game Centre leaderboard integration. A direct link to where I can learn how to do the implementation will be very much appreciated. Thank you!